# unable to execute shell script on Azure pipelines

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have added a task in Azure pipelines, the aim of task is to Enable WinRM on Remote Windows Servers.

Definition of task is below:

```
set -x
pwd
"cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts"
echo $/
sudo ./temp.sh
echo $?
```

I tried different variables but still no luck, the issue is, it is not able to change directory because of white space, I have double quotes around it but still not working, maybe I am not using the correct PreDefined variable?

Error message is as below:

```
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5826778Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5826827Z Task         : Command Line
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5826855Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5826885Z Version      : 2.146.1
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5827075Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5827104Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2019-02-25T23:39:09.5827131Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7013466Z Generating script.
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7057060Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/69f83a50-dbda-4ddc-a5ac-d658cebf6030.sh
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7110679Z /home/vsts/work/r1/a
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7110949Z $/
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7115232Z + pwd
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7115916Z + 'cd /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts'
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7116546Z /home/vsts/work/_temp/69f83a50-dbda-4ddc-a5ac-d658cebf6030.sh: line 3: cd /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts: No such file or directory
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7117181Z + echo '$/'
2019-02-25T23:39:09.7117272Z + sudo ./temp.sh
2019-02-25T23:39:09.9383963Z sudo: ./temp.sh: command not found
2019-02-25T23:39:09.9385705Z + echo 1
2019-02-25T23:39:09.9387433Z 1
2019-02-25T23:39:09.9478312Z ##[section]Finishing: Enable WinRM
```

Have a look at the output below, not sure why it cannot excute?

```
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977014Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977119Z Task         : Command Line
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977157Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977195Z Version      : 2.146.1
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977413Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977452Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2019-02-26T03:47:57.4977490Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6351017Z Generating script.
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6400544Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/d66aeba8-bdab-42b1-8988-cb139d4169a9.sh
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6466344Z /home/vsts/work/r1/a
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6466863Z $
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6474398Z + pwd
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6475184Z + cd '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts/'
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6475966Z + echo '$'
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476271Z + ls
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476447Z azure_rm.py
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476490Z InstallWinRM.sh
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476558Z temp.sh
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476708Z 0
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476917Z + echo 0
2019-02-26T03:47:57.6476972Z + sudo ./temp.sh
2019-02-26T03:47:57.9981782Z sudo: ./temp.sh: command not found
2019-02-26T03:47:58.0025055Z + echo 1
2019-02-26T03:47:58.0025466Z 1
2019-02-26T03:47:58.0111749Z ##[section]Finishing: Enable WinRM
```

I have added double quotes but still not working?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Downloading drop/terraform/scripts/temp.sh to /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts/temp.sh

Downloaded drop/terraform/scripts/temp.sh to /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Terraform Build Phase/drop/terraform/scripts/temp.sh

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working when I am using the same path.

Comment: Your quoting is off, `"cd path"` tries to execute the string `cd path` as a command, which of course is invalid. You want `cd "path"` to run the command `cd` with the string `path` as its quoted argument. Voting to close  as trivial typo.

Answer (score 3):

There were several issues which caused me the grief from running the simple script on Azure Release Pipeline, listed as below:

1. The double quote should have been like below:

   `cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/"_Terraform Build Phase"/drop/terraform/scripts`
2. The script itself needs executable permissions, not sure what happened on the Agent box but unless explicit chmod is done, it won't execute.

   `sudo chmod +x temp.sh`
3. I did dos2unix on the script from my end, still, there were control M characters, so I had to run the below trick to overcome them, so it becomes executable:

   `sed -i -e 's/\r$//' temp.sh`
4. Doing all the above allowed the script to execute! however, I didn't incorporate non-interactive Azure CLI Login, which errored out and did not provision resources. Fixed by the following:

   `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name shuiexample --password "Password012!!"`

   `az login --service-principal -u $appID --password $password --tenant $tenant`

   Anyone has better approach, steps please let me know.

Comment: Azure Devops pipelines are incredibly faulty! I am having problems running "sed" commands. They work like a charm in ANY ubuntu, but on the devops agent they don't work :(

Comment: Yes, I know. Suggest you raise a ticket in Visual Studio Community or Visual Studio Development Community